# rails url_for doesn't generate the same url from different pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with my website's urls.
I have 2 routes for the same action, the raw one and a rewritten url :

```
get '/page/:id'                  => 'page#view'
get '/:username/:rewritten_url'  => 'page#view'
```

Everything's work fine except when I try to generate a raw url from a rewritten page. Example :

I have 2 pages : one with a rewritten url and the second without (I don't have a rewritten url ).

```
page_id : 1
rewritten_url : /my-super-page

page_id : 2
rewritten_url : nil
```

My problem is when I try to generate a link to the page 2 using the url_for method, from the page 1.

- It doesn't work if i'm on the page 1 with the rewritten url. url_for generates for me the following raw url : /my-super-page?id=2 (instead of /page/2)
- It works if i'm on the page 1 with the raw url.

Also, it works if I try to generate a rewritten link from either a raw page or a rewritten page.

**EDIT**

Here is one url_for call which fail (the simpliest I could) :

```
url_for(controller: 'page', action: 'view', id: '3423423423')
# returns /my-super-page?id=3423423423
```

Normally, I have an override of the url_for method but I disabled it the time to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you add your exact calls to `url_for` and what they return? for example, `url_for(page_id: 1, rewritten_url: "/my-super-page")`

Comment: thank you. I edited my post to add a call. It's the simpliest call that I can do and it fails...

Comment: Please include the other call AND their return values. It's hard to diagnose a problem without seeing the code and the output!!

Comment: I added the return but I don't understand the url_for behavior. There's no link between /my-super-page and the page with id=3423423423, so it shouldn't generate a link to another page, using the current page url (the method seems not to read the controller and action parameters).